# Add to queue while iterating in another thread

Tags: java

In my game, I receive inputs from the clients as events which I am storing in a queue.

```
private Queue<Event> unprocessedEvents = new LinkedList<>();

@Override
public void onEvent(@NotNull Event event) {
    unprocessedEvents.add(event);
}
```

The queue gets processed 10 times per second in the server tick on a separate thread.

```
Iterator<Event> eventIterator = unprocessedEvents.iterator();
while (eventIterator.hasNext()) {
    Event event = eventIterator.next();

    //Handle the input from the client/server
    Event event = input(event);

    //Remove the event from the unprocessed inputs
    eventIterator.remove(); //ConcurrentModificationException
}
```

Sometimes I'm receiving a `ConcurrentModificationException` when I'm trying to insert an event while iterating the queue. Now I'm not sure what the best solution is to handle this for queues?

Should I use a `synchronized` block here? `Collections.synchronizedList()`, `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, `BlockingQueue`?

Can I maintain a separate queue and add the new queue to `unprocessedEvents` using  `addAll()`?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) since it natively handles concurrent thread accesses.

Comment: Why would you choose ```ConcurrentLinkedQueue``` over ```LinkedBlockingQueue``` in this particular scenario?

Comment: @Verhelst As the name says it is a blocking queue. You don't want that. You just want to push the inputs into the queue and process concurrently.

Comment: Also, you might wanna check the thread safe methods to access data from the queue if you are modifying the queue concurrently. Most of the times, methods coming from list interface are not thread safe.